# Porque mi tabla muestra los valores de esta manera?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, controller

Cabe acotar que lo que quiero hacer es que la tabla muestre los datos cuando se hace click sobre el boton "Iniciar".

http://prnt.sc/eu4j4n

```
package simulador;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class Proceso {
    public SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty nombre = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleIntegerProperty quantum = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleDoubleProperty recursos = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty estado = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleIntegerProperty tiempo = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public SimpleIntegerProperty getId() {
    return id;
}
public SimpleStringProperty getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public SimpleIntegerProperty getQuantum() {
    return quantum;
}
public SimpleDoubleProperty getRecursos() {
    return recursos;
}
public SimpleStringProperty getEstado() {
    return estado;
}
public SimpleIntegerProperty getTiempo() {
    return tiempo;
}
}

    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {



    @FXML private TableView <Proceso> tablaInfo;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaId;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaNombre;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaQuantum;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaRecursos;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaEstado;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaTiempo;

    public ObservableList<Proceso> lista;    


    @FXML
    private void botonIniciarClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        for (int i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++){
            int Q = (int)((Math.random()*29)+1);
            Proceso proceso = new Proceso();
            proceso.id.set(i);
            proceso.nombre.set("Proceso " + i);
            proceso.quantum.set(Q);
            proceso.recursos.set(1);
            proceso.estado.set("Ejecutando");
            proceso.tiempo.set(1);
            lista.add(proceso);           
        }


    }
    private void iniciarTabla(){
        columnaId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Proceso,Integer>("id"));
        columnaNombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Proceso,String>("nombre"));
        columnaQuantum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Proceso,Integer>("quantum"));
        columnaRecursos.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Proceso,Double>("recursos"));
        columnaEstado.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Proceso,String>("estado"));
        columnaTiempo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Proceso,Integer>("tiempo"));

        lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tablaInfo.setItems(lista);

    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        this.iniciarTabla();


    }    

}
```

Comment: Y donde esta tu codigo?, postealo para ver si te podemos apoyar

Comment: Sin tu código no te podemos ayudar

Comment: "Esta manera" sin mostrar la manera no sirve mucho para encontrar el problema, podrías dar un poco más información sobre tus inquietudes.

Comment: Mi error, primera vez que posteo aqui, ya adjunte el codigo (creo que de manera correcta)

Comment: Hola amigo, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Recuerda siempre añadir parte de tu trabajo en las preguntas que hagas para evitar molestias entre los usuarios que responden. :) Buen dia!

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Muchas gracias

Comment: No manejo Java, pero casos similares (particularmente en .NET) me ha ocurrido cuando el dato es una clase (o lgun tipo de dato personalizado) y no el dato a mostrar (string, integer, float,.... alguno de estos pero a si simple). Se esta mostrando el "PropertyValueFactory" y no el valor que tiene asignado de cada columna

Comment: Los campos no son objetos que tu tablet reconoce entonces lo muestra desde que tipo es tienes que cambiarlo a string o int tipos que si mostrsra

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que modificar tu clase para poder acceder a lo valores correctamente definiendo los accesores:

```
    public class Proceso {
        public SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        public SimpleStringProperty nombre = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public SimpleIntegerProperty quantum = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        public SimpleDoubleProperty recursos = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        public SimpleStringProperty estado = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public SimpleIntegerProperty tiempo = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(Integer newValue) {
        return id.set(newValue);
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre.get();
    } 

    public void setNombre(String newValue) {
        return nombre.set(newValue);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getNombre() {
       return nombre;
    }

...
...
...
 }
```

Comment: Mil gracias, no me habia fijado en eso.